# How to get client Host name of request in REST API

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, request-headers

Currently I am working with Rest API(Spring MVC). UI Part is developed in Angular JS. this project will integrate any of the domain.

For example : **www.xyz.com** containing my register button
              **www.abc.com** also may contain my register button.

When the request I received from user, I need to find out that, from which domain the request is coming?

Tried with the following:

```
@GET
@Path("/gethostname")
@Produces("application/json")
public void test(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @RequestBody JSONObject inputObj) {
    System.out.println("=========> "+httpHeaders.getHeaderString("host"));
}
```

But it return REST API(server) Host name. How can I get client host name?

Comment: or provide different url to different domain like <yourHost>/api/v1/register?domain=abc, <yourHost>/api/v1/register?domain=xyz and then you can read the domain variable.

Comment: @Pulkit My requirement is like this. thats why.

Comment: i can provide a code snippet in which onClick of button you will get client's host name, if required I can provide you that.

Comment: ya Pulkit. share it ASAP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways for you to get hostname

By calling below code on server side, please note that this will come as null if url is directly entered in browser.

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

Check this image[image]

Or you can provide below code to be added on client side and on server you can read the value of `domain` which will return hostname

```
<input type="button" value="Register" onClick="call()"/>
<script>
function call(){
    var domain=window.location.hostname;
    window.open('http://<your-hostname>/register?domain='+domain,'_self');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add HttpServletRequest request to your method definition and then use the Servlet API to get the Client remote address

```
@GET
@Path("/gethostname")
@Produces("application/json")
public void test(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @RequestBody JSONObject inputObj,, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("=========> "+request.getRemoteAddr());
}
```

Comment: It returns IP address of server. I need host name of client request.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the Origin

`httpHeaders.getOrigin()`

This returns the string which will tell you the origin of the request in your case 
http://www.yoursampleurl.com .

Comment: No getOrigin() is exist in httpHeaders.

Comment: if you use org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders it will have  getOrigin() method.

Comment: @MegalaPerumal Hello, getOrigin() is exist in Spring   you can find  it here.
 
java.lang.String getOrigin() Return the value of the Origin header.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html

Comment: Fro reference you can check
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#getOrigin()

Comment: when I am trying to import  org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders I am getting exception. I am handling this in Jersy REST API  javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders. this not have getOrigin().

Comment: you can use getRequestHeader("Origin"); to get the Orgin header value in javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.  It returns List<String> as values. In this case Origin will have a single value. so the first element will contain your desired information